How to make sense of a uniform distribution over the real numbers (or on some other unbounded set)?
"Pick a random real number," seems innocuous enough. Thinking about the math though, it does not seem to work. Such a CDF would have to have a constant slope yet have $\underset{x\rightarrow -\infty}{\text{lim}} F_X(x)= 0$ and $\underset{x\rightarrow +\infty}{\text{lim}} F_X(x)= 1$.
Every sloped line fails these limit conditions.
Every horizontal line fails at least one of the limit conditions.
So it seems that $U\left(-\infty, \infty\right)$ would be nonsense. At the same time, "Pick a random real number," seems basic.
Can $U\left(-\infty, \infty\right)$ be made formal, perhaps through some trick of measure theory?
